# Save xlsx file in Desktop using Django

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I want to save a excel file in Desktop from my apps, the file path is depends on the user that she/he want to download the file.Give me some idea, Thank You.

> FileNotFoundError at /Registration/Registration/Report [Errno 2] No
> such file or directory:
> '/Users/{username}/Desktop/Registration_Report.xlsx'

I got the error above if I call the current username login:

```
import os
def registration_report(request):
    username = os.getlogin()

     ***excel codes here***

    wb.save("/Users/{username}/Desktop/Registration_Report.xlsx") ## path to save the xlsx file ##
```

If I put the exact path to desktop working good and I access the downloaded excel file, This is working but what I want is, the path is depend on the user machine where the file to save.

```
def registration_report(request):
     ***excel codes here***

        wb.save("/Users/myusername/Desktop/Registration_Report.xlsx")

***myusername is the exact machine login username that I use***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
"/Users/{username}/Desktop/Registration_Report.xlsx"
```

This is just a string. In order to inject the `username` value you need an f-string.

```
wb.save(f"/Users/{username}/Desktop/Registration_Report.xlsx")
```